# How To Resign The UITextView With Done Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextview, resignfirstresponder

i was wondering if any of you knew how to get access to that done button that appears above the keyboard when editing.

I have seen it before, above the keyboard there is a transparent black area and on the right there is a blue "Done" Button.

I could do this by hand with my own animations and buttons above the keyboard in my app to resign the UITextView, but i would prefer to use Apple GUI elements that people know.

So does anybody have any information about where this "Done" button comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really "get access" to that button, but through the UITextViewDelegate protocol, you essentially can:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html

Implement the

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

routine, and assign the UIViewController holding the textview to the textview' delegate.

Inside of that routine, you can do what you wish!  You will need to call the

```
resignFirstResponder
```

method.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder

You will have to implement the style of keyboard that implements that blue done button.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits

**FINAL ANSWER**

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```